# Test that a function awaits something before doing anything else

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Suppose I have a function that executes an asynchronous action (`doStuffAsync()`) and then intends to do some other stuff (`doOtherStuff()`).

`doStuffAsync()` returns a `Promise`.

Also assume everything is mockable.

How do I test that my function awaits `doStuffAsync()` before trying to `doOtherStuff()`?

I thought of mocking `doStuffAsync()` using `resolve => setTimeout(resolve(), timeout)`, but timeout-based testing looks very fragile.

Comment: You want to test the `await` keyword / the promise? In my opinion, you are supposed to test your code, not the language features.

Comment: No, I want to test that my function awaits something before starting to execute other code. There is a behavioural difference between `await doStuffAsync(); doOtherStuff();` and simply `doStuffAsync(); doOtherStuff();`. 

I would like to test that there **is** an `await`.

Comment: I do understand that there is a behavioral diff, but I don't see how you can test it :/ And personnaly, I wouldn't test it. If you're doing unit testing, you call a function, and you expect to get a given result. The internal behavior of the function is not the matter of the test.

Comment: Interesting question any way ;) I hope we'll see some good answers!

Comment: I had a very real bug related to not awaiting the async function – `doOtherStuff()` navigated away to another screen while I explicitly wanted it to happen only after `doStuffAsync()` is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag accessible by both `doStuffAsync` and `doOtherStuff`.

In `doStuffAsync()` write in that flag
In `doOtherStuff()` read from that flag and determine if it was written

Something like:

```js
var isAsyncRunning = false;
    
function doStuffAsync(){
  isAsyncRunning = true;
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      isAsyncRunning = false;
      resolve(); //irrelevant in this exercise 
    }, 1000);
  });
      
}
doStuffAsync(); 
function doOtherStuff(){
  if(isAsyncRunning){
    console.log("Async is running.");
  } else {
    console.log("Async is no longer running.");
  };

}
doOtherStuff();
setTimeout(() => {
  //calling doOtherStuff 2 seconds later..
  doOtherStuff();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Please provide the test too, I think this is the main interesting point. I don't think I get your point here.

Comment: I think you're thrown off by [tag:unit-testing] and the *"test that function awaits"* wording. The fact that a function *"awaits"* means it was called. To test that, you can check the flag I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

I managed to complete it with a less ugly solution than `setTimeout` – `setImmediate`.

```
function testedFunction() {
    await MyModule.doStuffAsync();
    MyModule.doOtherStuff();
}

it('awaits the asynchronous stuff before doing anything else', () => {
    // Mock doStuffAsync() so that the promise is resolved at the end
    // of the event loop – which means, after the test. 
    // -
    const doStuffAsyncMock = jest.fn();
    const delayedPromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => setImmediate(resolve()));
    doStuffAsyncMock.mockImplementation(() => delayedPromise);

    const doOtherStuffMock = jest.fn();

    MyModule.doStuffAsync = doStuffAsyncMock;
    MyModule.doOtherStuffMock = doOtherStuffMock;

    testedFunction();

    expect(doOtherStuffMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
}
```

`setImmediate` will put off the resolution of your promise to the end of the event loop, which is after your test completes.

So, your assert that `doOtherStuff()` was not invoked:

- Will pass if there is an `await` inside the `testedFunction`
- Will fail if there isn't.